# Filter SelectListItem value using some condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4, html-select

I have one SelectListItem for DropDownList. I have to filter based on some condition. If I try adding the condition then its gives me an error like this (LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression). I ll be adding that code here. Please guide me to solve this.

**Code**

```
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IssueId = (from txt in Db.Issues where txt.BibId == BibId
            select new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = txt.Description,
            Value = txt.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = true,
        });
        SelectList IssueIds = new SelectList(IssueId, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.IssueId = IssueIds;
```

Thanks

Comment: So what's the error? "some error" tells us nothing. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

LINQ2EF does not know ToString() but after AsEnumerable() you'll get a local collection when ToString() is implemented.

```
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IssueId = 
(from txt in Db.Issues.Where(e => e.BibId == BibId).AsEnumerable()
    select new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = txt.Description,
        Value = txt.Id.ToString(),
        Selected = true     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That extension does not seem to be sorted by linq to Entities but you could just do the mapping once you have the issues, e.g.

```
var issues = (from issue in Db.Issues 
               where issue .BibId == BibId 
               select issue ).ToList();     

IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IssueId = (from txt in issues 
                                       where txt.BibId == BibId
                                      select new SelectListItem()
                                      {
                                        Text = txt.Description,
                                        Value = txt.Id.ToString(),
                                        Selected = true,
                                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq To Sql can't generate TSQL for txt.Id.ToString()

You will need to iterate the result instead after executing the query, or cast to Enumerable as xeondev suggests.